# How can I efficiently store/retrieve data about grid edges?

Tags: c#

If this is the wrong stackexchange website for this question, please direct me elsewhere!

I have a regular 2-dimensional grid of nodes. I would also like to store data about the edges between nodes of the grid, and I'm not sure how to do this in an efficient way.

The three ideas that immediately occurred to me both have cons, and I'm not sure which is preferable, or if, indeed, there is a better way entirely.

1. **Store edge data in a 2d array.** Since the graph nodes essentially form a 2d array, you can simply store edge data in a normal two dimensional array -- 0,0 is the bottom left node, 1,0 is to the right of it, and 0,1 is directly "above" it, etc.

The issue with this method is data duplication - the data about the edge between 0,0 and 0,1 is stored in two separate places. Whenever the data needs to be updated, you need to update it in both places, and, of course, you have extra memory overhead, since you need to hold potentially twice as much data (even if half of it is duplicated)

2. **Store only the "top" and "left" edges in a 2d array.** This is an extension of method 1, which avoids storing the redundant data. However, this makes retrieving and storing the data even more difficult, since you now need 3 calls to collect or set all the edges of a node (x,y; x+1,y; and x,y-1).
3. **Use a `dictionary<<<x,y>,<x,y>>,Edge>` dictionary (tuple of points) to store and retrieve data about the edge between two nodes in the graph.**

This avoids the redundancy, but dictionary lookup is slower than arrays, and it's not possible to get all 4 edges at once (a dictionary which takes in a node and returns 4 edges would solve the latter, but reintroduce redundancy issues). For my purposes, I'm primarily interested in all possible edges between a small group of nodes, so not retrieving all the nodes is not a huge issue.

Right now, I'm leaning towards method #1 and just sucking up and dealing with the redundant data. Is there a better way to store / retrieve data about edges, or is this the best that it gets.

Example - storing color in Edge:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming everything will fit in memory and your edges are not extremely sparse, I would go with *"Store only the "top" and "left" edges in a 2d array"* as it probably has the best cache performance of the options you listed.

> However, this makes retrieving and storing the data even more difficult, since you now need 3 calls to collect or set all the edges of a node (x,y; x+1,y; and x,y-1).

I don't understand what you mean by this. Everything should be encapsulated in a class to an interface which is convenient to use. If you find yourself needing to set all edges of a node then write a method to do so.

Comment: That is good advice. I'd have probably done it anyway, but thanks for pointing out that having 3 calls is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what would you suggest if the edges *are* sparse?

Comment: @RavenDreamer I honestly don't know. Probably would go with a dictionary if they couldn't fit in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to make a big 1D list of edge objects, and then link them appropriately to the nodes. For example, your node class could have `TopEdge`, `LeftEdge`, `BottomEdge`, and `RightEdge` members, each of which would be a reference to the some object in the edge list.

This might be a little more complicated to set up initially, but would avoid data duplication and provide easy access to the appropriate edges from the nodes.

You also may want to read up on [graph theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28data_structure%29) if you want a more formal solution.

Comment: Hm. I want to store value data (an Edge struct). I'm a little dicey about passing around struct references. It should still work, though.

Comment: Yeah, if you want to do structs then this may not work so well. Why not use classes though? If you are concerned about performance I would code it up in a simple way first and then do some profiling to see if it works for you.